# gaps between item in recyclerview increasing while list updating dynamically and repeatedly android

Tags: android

i am showing a list coming from server with recyclerview,request to update list executing after certain time and if new item, it will be added to the list but after every request executing gaps between items in recyclerview getting large.
[image]

[image]

my xml code to show recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_notification_list_show"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.systechdigital.webadeal.NotificationListShowActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_notification_list_show"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId"
        android:background="#c2bfbf"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/emptyViewTvId"
        android:text="There is no notification"

        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

recyclerview adapter code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.2"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_notificatoinListShowId"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/proNameTvId"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_notificatoinListShowId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notificationMsgTvId"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/proNameTvId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notificationTimeTvId"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notificationMsgTvId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_notificatoinListShowId"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/circleButtonId"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_notification"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter java code:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        NotificationClass notificationClass=notificationClassArrayList.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context).load(notificationClass.getProfile_pic_id()).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(holder.image_notificatoinListShow);
        holder.proNameTv.setText(notificationClass.getFirst_name()+" "+ notificationClass.getLast_name());
        holder.notificationMsgTvId.setText(notificationClass.getActionText());
        if(notificationClass.getIsViewed().contains("0")){
            holder.circleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.circleButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Long.valueOf(notificationClass.getLastModify())*1000);
        holder.notificationTimeTvId.setText(timestamp.toString());


    }
```

list show java code activity:

```
 notificationListShowAdapter = new NotificationListShowAdapter(recyclerView.getContext(), list);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(contextNotificationActivity);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationListShowAdapter);

            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(contextNotificationActivity,
                    layoutManager.getOrientation());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
            notificationListShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I'm suspicious about your use of `scaleType="fitXY"` on a RecyclerView. What do you want to accomplish there and are you sure that can work? As far as I know, that works only on ImageViews. Also, there's a RelativeLayout in your RecyclerView layout that has a layout_width, a layout_height and a layout_weight. Normally, a layout_width is only taking into account when either width or height, or both, are 0.

Comment: i was just testing if it is work or not, nothing more. do you have any solution on this?

Comment: something is wrong with yours single item view xml.!

Comment: could you find the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend giving fixed height to the `notificationMsgTvId` and then running the code again. The `wrap_content` inside list elements are a pain sometimes.
2. Could you also try giving a color as background to `notificationMsgTvId` and check if that is the view that is becoming larger?
3. Also, I would recommend adding a view with grey background at the end of layout as divider instead of using a `DividerItemDecoration` :)

Try these steps and let me know if the issue still exists. Most of the times, this should solve the above issue.

Cheers!

Comment: i checked with your suggestions, increasing just cell size not text or other views

Comment: Ok, here is a guess. `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` remove this from the RecyclerView. That property is generally used with `ImageView` as far as I know.

Comment: yes i also know the same but tried after this mess up.okay again i am trying

Comment: ha.. is it? if you don't mind, could you share a sample json/model that you're using to update the recyclerview. also let me know if the new value you receive from server is added to the adapter as single item or array of items.

Comment: please check how i added the json

Comment: ok. let me check and try to reproduce the scenario. will update the answer once I am done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143764/discussion-between-rahul-raveendran-and-aaa).

Comment: @AAA did you get a chance to look at the chat message I sent?

Comment: i requested you to give me one running code. and it would be best if you could solved it without reloaded the view.

Comment: @AAA due to my time limits I haven't created an entire project to debug this today. I have created a sample code that explains my point and have updated the old answer with it. Please check and let me know if you need clarifications. This is the method I follow when I have similar situation to handle. Hope it solves the issue.

Comment: i have found the reason of increasing gap automatically in recyclerview.it was because of DividerItemDecoration. i omitted that and handle with manually from xml

Comment: have reverted the answer. accept it if you feel like so ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in one of my projects. I managed to solve this by disabling the `RecyclerView`'s animation using the following piece of code:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
something is wrong in your layout weight sum.!

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" 
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.0" 
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                >



<ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_notificatoinListShowId"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/proNameTvId"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_notificatoinListShowId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notificationMsgTvId"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/proNameTvId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notificationTimeTvId"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notificationMsgTvId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_notificatoinListShowId"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/circleButtonId"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_notification"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its related to width so should not be reason for this

Comment: are you sure then why you are using match partent as a width.?
just set height 0dp